# Buy whatever/anything/everything: similar meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do these three sentences have the same meaning?

1. He can buy whatever he wants.
2. He can buy anything he wants.
3. He can buy everything he wants.

Comment: What do you think, @Wu Xilang?

Comment: @JavaLatte I think they are the same, but I am not sure.

Comment: They use different words, and therefore have different meanings. The different meanings suggest the same overall meaning, but in different ways, and so might be appropriate in different circumstances. For example, there is a big difference between anything and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would consider that all of these describe a man who has enough money to purchase anything he might want to purchase.

Comment: Are they all idiomatic?

Comment: @WuXiliang Yes, in the sense that they are all natural-sounding to a native (American, at least) English speaker. None of them sound 'forced', none of them sound as if they come from someone who does not speak English as their first language.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not clear that they always mean the same.

While #3 would almost always have the meaning that I think @rcook is suggesting, where "everything" means "any and all", #1 and #2 are not so clear. They *could* mean "any and all", but they might instead mean "any one", and context may be needed to decide which it is.

To see that, imagine the following scenario. An elderly man, his adult daughter, and her kid--his grandson--are on a shopping trip. To begin with, the daughter wants to visit a couple of stores on her own, and so the man takes his grandson to a toy store. The daughter will join them there later. The following dialog ensues

> **Man:** Go ahead kiddo, choose a toy; *anything* you want.
>
> **Kid:** Really, grandpa? I can pick *anything*?
>
> **Man:** You got it, kiddo. *Anything*.
>
> [The man sits and has a coffee while the kid hunts for a toy. Ten minutes later--the kid is still searching--the daughter arrives and sits down with her father.]
>
> **Woman:** Oh dad! You're not buying him *another* toy, are you!?
>
> [Man grins at her, mischievously, and nods]
>
> **Woman:** [sighing] You're a menace! Well fine, but I don't want him buying any more of that slime you got him last time.
>
> **Man:** Ah, ah, no, no! I already promised him.
>
> **Woman:** [now groaning] Dad! What *exactly* did you promise?
>
> **Man:** I told him that **he can buy *anything* he wants.** Now stop rolling your eyes at me and let me get you a coffee and a bun.

Most native speakers would interpret that use of "anything" to mean "any one" not "any and all". (And I reckon they'd interpret it that way even if the grandfather had not used, at the start, the explicit "a toy".)